# "Saving, please wait" custom message displaying current operations

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a huge web form (30k lines of code with js included) and when I click save, it will take some time.
So I want to dim the page under the alert, show a custom message saying "Saving, please wait" with the page under that and maybe display the operations that are happening under so it has to know what the controller is doing at the moment (saving attachments or...).
An alert is not what I want, I don't want to give the user the chance to cancel the saving when he already clicked it.

Any special or usual way to achieve this?

Comment: What is being saved when you click save?

Comment: The form is submitted, but it takes around 8 seconds to do.

Comment: So here's my confusion, and why I need you to clarify. You list the size of your page, with code, as (part of) the reason for wanting to show a saving message. So what is it that you're saving? Form data? And where do you go after the data is saved? Back to this same page?

Comment: When I submit the form (when I click the SAVE button) it will save all the records on the DB. Since the form has 20 sections and from 2 to 5 items per section, it will take a while to perform that operation. Having the end user click the SAVE button and having the page that doesn't look like doing anything (because its busy saving) its not good, so I need dim the view, display a message and that message should contain which section is currently saving at each moment. No need of OK/Cancel button, just the message

Comment: Ok. So you have two problems. One, you need to make the page load time better. That needs to happen. Can't help you with that without seeing some code, though. Second, you need to save your page data with AJAX instead of posting it old-school. If you save the page data using AJAX, you can pop up the saving message before initiating the AJAX request, and then take it down on the success callback for the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a "loading div" that will sit over the page and stop you from being able to click anywhere.

You can call it like this:

Script

```
window.onbeforeunload = function showLoadDiv() {
    $('#loadingWrapper').fadeIn();
};
```

CSS:

```
#loadingWrapper{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:url(../Images/transparentimage.png) repeat;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: 922 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loadingWrapper"></div>
```

Then, once the page has loaded you can either just do `$('#loadingWrapper').fadeOut();` or if you are calling a new action once the process has complete, that will remove the loading panel.

Comment: Don't forget to change transparentimage.png for something else - could just be a semi-transparent image to fade out the page, then I would also include something else in that `loadingWrapper` to actually show a message

Comment: What if he isn't loading his page data with AJAX? Any preprocessing he's doing on the server before sending the page to the browser will still take time without the benefit of this overlay.

Comment: my answer has nothing to do with AJAX, this will create a loading panel to fade over the page whilst the request is being processed. if the OP was using AJAX, then instead they would use `$(document).ajaxStart(function () { $('#loadingWrapper').fadeIn(); });`

Comment: If part of the reason for his insanely long load time is that he's executing a great deal of code in the controller, then your loading panel will not show until the javascript that calls for it gets sent to the user's browser. That means that, however long the controller takes before sending page content, you will still have a blank-screened browser with a progress bar instead of your overlay.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your answer for a moment, in part because the OP's question mentions the size of the page. If the page is already loaded, then yes, your solution will be fine.

Comment: And tried to remove the downvote, but it's telling me that the vote is locked in unless the answer is edited. Please accept my apology for that.

Comment: It works as expected but still have to show the progress on that div. What is the solution? render a partial view for that div and change it during the controller execution?

Comment: What I would do, is to write to a database table as each process completes, then you can do an Ajax refresh on a partial view to read the last rows from the table.